# Cypher: return both nodes and edges from a query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a beginner Cypher question. I have a query like this:

```
MATCH (rebecca:Person {name:"Rebecca"})-[1..2]->(companies:Company)
RETURN companies
```

This returns all the companies within two hops of Rebecca, but it only returns the final company nodes. How do I see the edges and the intermediate nodes as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return only entities that are aliased.

```
MATCH (rebecca:Person {name:"Rebecca"})-[1..2]->(companies:Company)
RETURN companies
```

Add a `r` alias to your relationships :

```
MATCH (rebecca:Person {name:"Rebecca"})-[r*1..2]->(companies:Company)
RETURN companies, r
```

For returning intermediate nodes, you can make it a path :

```
MATCH p=(rebecca:Person {name:"Rebecca"})-[r*1..2]->(companies:Company)
RETURN companies, relationships(p), nodes(p)
```

You can also return the company along with a map of (relationship, startnode, endnode) :

```
MATCH (rebecca:Person {name:"Rebecca"})-[r*1..2]->(companies:Company)
RETURN companies,
       extract(x IN r | {rel: x, start: startNode(x), end: endNode(x)})
```